# difference between st_accum and st_collect

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Can anyone please tell me the difference between ST_Accum and ST_Collect of PostGIS.
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Accum.html

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html

Answer (score 6):

The `ST_Accum` function creates an array of input geometries, while `ST_Collect` creates a Geometry collection.

Think of it this way. If your inputs are a Bunch of Points, `ST_Accum` will return an array of points, while `ST_Collect` will return a Multi-Point.

If the inputs were lines, the `ST_Collect` would return a Multi-Line and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The role of `ST_accum` and `ST_Collect` are different :

- The `ST_Accum` functions creates an array of input geometries ([doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Accum.html)),
- while `ST_Collect` function create a geometry from an input array ([doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html)).

So, you can use the output of `ST_Accum` as the input of `ST_Collect`.

The inverse will create an array with one element.